# minecraft Failed to receive data from URL: llibrary_patrons.json

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

cuando abro mi minecraft con 72 mods y intento crear el mundo me crashea el juego aunque tenga casi 13gb de ram este es el error completo

```
Error detectado: Minecraft se ha cerrado inesperadamente. Vuelve a iniciar Minecraft. 
Error:
[23:07:40] [pool-3-thread-1/ERROR] [LLibrary]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

WARNING: coremods are present:
  llibrary (llibrary-core-1.0.11-1.12.2.jar)
  McLib core mod (mclib-2.0-1.12.2.jar)
  FutureMC (future-mc-1.12.2-0.2.4.jar)
  ForgelinPlugin (Forgelin-1.8.4.jar)
  midnight (themidnight-0.3.5.jar)
  OpenModsCorePlugin (OpenModsLib-1.12.2-0.12.2.jar)
  Quark Plugin (Quark-r1.6-179.jar)
  CreativePatchingLoader (CreativeCore_v1.10.16_mc1.12.2.jar)
  CustomSkinLoader (skins-forge.jar)
  BewitchmentFMLLoadingPlugin (bewitchment-1.12.2-0.0.22.34.jar)
  wings (wings-1.1.4-1.12.2.jar)
  LoadingPlugin (ChunkAnimator-MC1.12-1.2.jar)
Contact their authors BEFORE contacting forge

// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 3/2/24 11:07 PM
Description: Failed to receive data from URL: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gegy1000/7a6d39cf7a2c1f794ffb9037e8146adc/raw/llibrary_patrons.json

java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gegy1000/7a6d39cf7a2c1f794ffb9037e8146adc/raw/llibrary_patrons.json
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1835)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1432)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1429)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.util.WebUtils.readURL(WebUtils.java:60)
    at net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.util.WebUtils.lambda$readURLAsync$0(WebUtils.java:105)
    at net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.util.WebUtils$$Lambda$995/168779025.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 502847824 bytes (479 MB) / 1989672960 bytes (1897 MB) up to 12884901888 bytes (12288 MB)
    JVM Flags: 7 total; -Xms512M -Xmx13824M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2860 Optifine OptiFine_1.12.2_HD_U_G5 82 mods loaded, 80 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

    | State | ID                    | Version           | Source                                   | Signature                                |
    |:----- |:--------------------- |:----------------- |:---------------------------------------- |:---------------------------------------- |
    | LCH   | minecraft             | 1.12.2            | minecraft.jar                            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | mcp                   | 9.42              | minecraft.jar                            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | FML                   | 8.0.99.99         | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar            | e3c3d50c7c986df74c645c0ac54639741c90a557 |
    | LCH   | forge                 | 14.23.5.2860      | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar            | e3c3d50c7c986df74c645c0ac54639741c90a557 |
    | LCH   | creativecoredummy     | 1.0.0             | minecraft.jar                            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | openmodscore          | 0.12.2            | minecraft.jar                            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | customskinloader      | 14.17             | skins-forge.jar                          | 52885f395e68f42e9b3b629ba56ecf606f7d4269 |
    | LCH   | securitycraft         | v1.8.19.3         | 1.12.2]+SecurityCraft+v1.8.19.3.jar      | None                                     |
    | LCH   | jei                   | 4.15.0.289        | jei_1.12.2-4.15.0.289 (1).jar            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | abyssalcraft          | 1.10.2            | AbyssalCraft-1.12.2-1.10.2.jar           | 220f10d3a93b3ff5fbaa7434cc629d863d6751b9 |
    | LCH   | thedragonlib          | 1.12.2-5.3.0      | thedragonlib-1.12.2-5.3.0.jar            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | armorplus             | 1.12.2-11.28.0.69 | armorplus-1.12.2-11.28.0.69.jar          | None                                     |
    | LCH   | quark                 | r1.6-179          | Quark-r1.6-179.jar                       | None                                     |
    | LCH   | autoreglib            | 1.3-32            | AutoRegLib-1.3-32.jar                    | None                                     |
    | LCH   | baubles               | 1.5.2             | Baubles-1.12-1.5.2.jar                   | None                                     |
    | LCH   | botania               | r1.10-363         | Botania+r1.10-363.jar                    | None                                     |
    | LCH   | patchouli             | 1.0-21            | Patchouli-1.0-21.jar                     | None                                     |
    | LCH   | bewitchment           | 0.22.34           | bewitchment-1.12.2-0.0.22.34.jar         | None                                     |
    | LCH   | beyondtheveil         | 1.12.2-0.2.2      | BeyondTheVeil-1.12.2-0.2.2.jar           | None                                     |
    | LCH   | croparia              | 2.4               | Croparia-2.5.jar                         | None                                     |
    | LCH   | guideapi              | 1.12-2.1.8-63     | Guide-API-1.12-2.1.8-63 (1).jar          | None                                     |
    | LCH   | bloodmagic            | 1.12.2-2.4.3-105  | BloodMagic-1.12.2-2.4.3-105.jar          | None                                     |
    | LCH   | bountifulbaubles      | 0.0.1             | Bountiful+Baubles-1.12.2-0.1.6.jar       | None                                     |
    | LCH   | chickens              | 6.1.0             | chickens-6.1.0.jar                       | None                                     |
    | LCH   | chunkanimator         | 1.2               | ChunkAnimator-MC1.12-1.2.jar             | None                                     |
    | LCH   | cookingforblockheads  | 6.5.0             | CookingForBlockheads_1.12.2-6.5.0.jar    | None                                     |
    | LCH   | cosmeticarmorreworked | 1.12.2-v4a        | CosmeticArmorReworked-1.12.2-v4a.jar     | aaaf83332a11df02406e9f266b1b65c1306f0f76 |
    | LCH   | opframe               | 1.4.0             | OnlinePicFrame_v1.4.40_mc1.12.2.jar      | None                                     |
    | LCH   | playerrevive          | 1.0               | PlayerRevive_v1.2.35_mc1.12.2.jar        | None                                     |
    | LCH   | creativecore          | 1.10.0            | CreativeCore_v1.10.16_mc1.12.2.jar       | None                                     |
    | LCH   | cucumber              | 1.1.3             | Cucumber-1.12.2-1.1.3.jar                | None                                     |
    | LCH   | customnpcs            | 1.12              | CustomNPCs_1.12.2-(05Jul20).jar          | None                                     |
    | LCH   | cyclopscore           | 1.6.6             | CyclopsCore-1.12.2-1.6.6.jar             | bd0353b3e8a2810d60dd584e256e364bc3bedd44 |
    | LCH   | darknesslib           | 1.1.0             | DarknessLib-1.12.2-1.1.0.jar             | 220f10d3a93b3ff5fbaa7434cc629d863d6751b9 |
    | LCH   | ptrmodellib           | 1.0.5             | PTRLib-1.0.5 (2).jar                     | None                                     |
    | LCH   | props                 | 2.6.3             | Decocraft-2.6.3_1.12.2.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | defiledlands          | 1.4.3             | defiledlands-1.12.2-1.4.3.jar            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | divinerpg             | 1.6.4.1           | DivineRPG-1.6.4.1.jar                    | None                                     |
    | LCH   | ebwizardry            | 4.2.11            | ElectroblobsWizardry-4.2.11-MC1.12.2.jar | None                                     |
    | LCH   | mclib                 | 2.0               | mclib-2.0-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
    | LCH   | emoticons             | 0.5               | emoticons-0.5-1.12.2-dist.jar            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | evilcraft             | 0.10.78           | EvilCraft-1.12.2-0.10.78.jar             | bd0353b3e8a2810d60dd584e256e364bc3bedd44 |
    | LCH   | evilcraftcompat       | 1.0.0             | EvilCraft-1.12.2-0.10.78.jar             | None                                     |
    | LCH   | extrautils2           | 1.0               | extrautils2-1.12-1.9.9.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | fakename              | 1.2               | Fakename+MC1.12.2+v1.2.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | fbp                   | 2.4.1             | FancyBlockParticles-1.12.x-2.4.1.jar     | None                                     |
    | LCH   | cursedlib             | 1.0.0             | FlameLib-1.12.2-0.0.7.jar                | None                                     |
    | LCH   | forgelin              | 1.8.4             | Forgelin-1.8.4.jar                       | None                                     |
    | LCH   | cfm                   | 6.3.1             | furniture-6.3.1-1.12.2.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | futuremc              | 0.2.4             | future-mc-1.12.2-0.2.4.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | gravestone            | 1.10.3            | gravestone-1.10.3.jar                    | None                                     |
    | LCH   | hatchery              | 2.2.2             | hatchery-1.12.2-2.2.2.jar                | None                                     |
    | LCH   | howlingmoon           | 0.9               | howlingmoon-1.12.2-0.9.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | waila                 | 1.8.26            | Hwyla-1.8.26-B41_1.12.2 (1).jar          | None                                     |
    | LCH   | journeymap            | 1.12.2-5.7.1      | journeymap-1.12.2-5.7.1.jar              | None                                     |
    | LCH   | morechickens          | 3.2.0             | morechickens-1.12.2-3.2.0.jar            | None                                     |
    | LCH   | moreplayermodels      | 1.12.2            | MorePlayerModels_1.12.2-(05Dec19).jar    | None                                     |
    | LCH   | roots                 | 1.12.2-3.0.30     | Roots-1.12.2-3.0.30.jar                  | None                                     |
    | LCH   | mysticalworld         | 1.12.2-1.8.4      | mysticalworld-1.12.2-1.8.4.jar           | None                                     |
    | LCH   | recipehandler         | 0.13              | No-More-Recipe-Conflict-Mod-1.12.2.jar   | None                                     |
    | LCH   | openmods              | 0.12.2            | OpenModsLib-1.12.2-0.12.2.jar            | d2a9a8e8440196e26a268d1f3ddc01b2e9c572a5 |
    | LCH   | harvestcraft          | 1.12.2zb          | Pam's+HarvestCraft+1.12.2zg.jar          | None                                     |
    | LCH   | xreliquary            | 1.12.2-1.3.4.796  | Reliquary-1.12.2-1.3.4.796.jar           | None                                     |
    | LCH   | lemonlib              | 1.3.0             | lemonlib-1.12.2-1.3.0.jar                | None                                     |
    | LCH   | statues               | 1.0.1             | statues-rechiseled-1.12.2-1.0.1.jar      | None                                     |
    | LCH   | stupidthings          | 1.1.6             | Stupid+Things-1.12.2-1.1.6.jar           | None                                     |
    | LCH   | stygian               | 1.0.4             | stygian-1.0.4.jar                        | None                                     |
    | LCH   | toroquest             | 1.12.2-5.3        | toroquest-1.12.2-5.3.jar                 | None                                     |
    | LCH   | uteamcore             | 2.2.5.147         | u_team_core-1.12.2-2.2.5.147.jar         | None                                     |
    | LCH   | usefulbackpacks       | 1.5.3.59          | useful_backpacks-1.12.2-1.5.3.59.jar     | None                                     |
    | LCH   | useless_sword         | 1.0.9             | UselessSword-1.12.2-V1.0.9.jar           | None                                     |
    | LCH   | vampiresneedumbrellas | 1.4               | VampiresNeedUmbrellas-1.12.2-1.5.jar     | None                                     |
    | LCH   | vampirism             | 1.6.2             | Vampirism-1.12.2-1.6.2 .jar              | None                                     |
    | LCH   | teamlapen-lib         | 1.6.2             | Vampirism-1.12.2-1.6.2 .jar              | None                                     |
    | LCH   | waystones             | 4.1.0             | Waystones_1.12.2-4.1.0.jar               | None                                     |
    | LCH   | llibrary              | 1.7.19            | llibrary-1.7.19-1.12.2.jar               | b9f30a813bee3b9dd5652c460310cfcd54f6b7ec |
    | LCH   | wings                 | 1.1.4             | wings-1.1.4-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |
    | LCH   | bauble_wings          | 1.0.0             | wings-1.1.4-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |
    | LCH   | midnight              | 0.3.5             | themidnight-0.3.5.jar                    | None                                     |
    | LC    | mysticallib           | 1.12.2-1.7.0      | mysticallib-1.12.2-1.7.0.jar             | None                                     |
    | UD    | mclib_core            | 2.0               | minecraft.jar                            | None                                     |
    | UD    | mobends_wings         | 1.0.0             | wings-1.1.4-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |

    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
llibrary (llibrary-core-1.0.11-1.12.2.jar)
  net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.core.plugin.LLibraryTransformer
  net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.core.patcher.LLibraryRuntimePatcher
McLib core mod (mclib-2.0-1.12.2.jar)
  mchorse.mclib.core.McLibCMClassTransformer
FutureMC (future-mc-1.12.2-0.2.4.jar)
  thedarkcolour.futuremc.asm.CoreTransformer
ForgelinPlugin (Forgelin-1.8.4.jar)
  
midnight (themidnight-0.3.5.jar)
  com.mushroom.midnight.core.transformer.MidnightClassTransformer
OpenModsCorePlugin (OpenModsLib-1.12.2-0.12.2.jar)
  openmods.core.OpenModsClassTransformer
Quark Plugin (Quark-r1.6-179.jar)
  vazkii.quark.base.asm.ClassTransformer
CreativePatchingLoader (CreativeCore_v1.10.16_mc1.12.2.jar)
  
CustomSkinLoader (skins-forge.jar)
  customskinloader.forge.loader.LaunchWrapper
BewitchmentFMLLoadingPlugin (bewitchment-1.12.2-0.0.22.34.jar)
  
wings (wings-1.1.4-1.12.2.jar)
  me.paulf.wings.server.asm.WingsRuntimePatcher
  me.paulf.wings.server.asm.mobends.WingsMoBendsRuntimePatcher
LoadingPlugin (ChunkAnimator-MC1.12-1.2.jar)
  lumien.chunkanimator.asm.ClassTransformer
    GL info: ~ERROR~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    OpenModsLib class transformers: [llama_null_fix:FINISHED],[horse_base_null_fix:FINISHED],[pre_world_render_hook:FINISHED],[player_render_hook:FINISHED],[horse_null_fix:FINISHED]
    Patchouli open book context: n/a
    OptiFine Version: OptiFine_1.12.2_HD_U_G5
    OptiFine Build: 20210124-142939
    Render Distance Chunks: 64
    Mipmaps: 4
    Anisotropic Filtering: 1
    Antialiasing: 0
    Multitexture: false
    Shaders: null
    OpenGlVersion: 4.6.0 Compatibility Profile Context 24.1.1.231127
    OpenGlRenderer: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics
    OpenGlVendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
    CpuCount: 12
```

he estado meterme a un mundo survival y no me ah dejado minecraft
y me aparece este error todo largo y solo pasa cuando uso forge
pero es una situacion mala puesto que queder de jugar con unos amigos y no pude por que los mods no dejaron si alguna duda esta echo con battly launcher

Comment: Bienvenido. Solo respondemos preguntas de programación. Al parecer crashea porque no encuentra un archivo en línea.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tus logs estás usando la librería llamada `llibrary` en su versión `1.7.19` lo que puedes verificar porque tienes un archivo que se llama `llibrary-1.7.19-1.12.2.jar`.

El problema ocurre porque esa versión de la librería está tratando de descargar un archivo [json](/questions/tagged/json) que subieron a github pero que actualmente lo borraron.

Esa librería ya tiene un [issue abierto](https://github.com/iLexiconn/LLibrary/issues/185) para el mismo error que reportas, y de momento allí recomiendan actualizar la versión a la `1.7.20`.

Comment: *"Revisando tus logs estás usando la librería"* -> dudo que él esté usando nada... es un jugador de minecraft que ha instalado mods nada más, no veo absolutamente nada en su pregunta que haga referencia a programar nada. Sus únicas pruebas han sido lanzar el juego intentando conectarse a un servidor en vez de un jugador... Esto es más una pregunta para el soporte del creador del mod con problemas que para SO, puesto que no parece que vaya a modificarle nada al código... con lo cual es una pregunta totalmente incorrecta para SO

Comment: @Benito-B bueno.. tampoco es como que la información le sirva a un usuario promedio de minecraft... recuerda que el sitio es usado por programadores y administradores de sistemas de todo el mundo por lo que la persona que pregunta no es el único con acceso a la información, justo, puede servir incluso a los de soporte técnico o creadores de mods. Respecto a que sea incorrecta, para ello te recomiendo plantearlo en el meta, yo la respondí porque tiene cosas que algunos desarrolladores podrían aprovechar en conocer.